# Calculate the probability given by three random variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $X_1,X_2,X_3$ be IID random variables, each with the density
$$f(x)=x e^{-x}\cdot 1_{(0,\infty)}(x).$$
Calculate $P(X_1+X_2+X_3>4,X_1+X_2<4)$.

Comment: OK, I think I can solve it. Give me few minutes, I will write it down.

Answer (score 0):

Let $Y=X_1+X_2$. $Y$ has the density:
$$g(x)=\int_0^t f(t-x)f(x)dx = \frac{e^{-t}t^3}{6}$$ for $t>0$. Now we want to calculate the final probability which is equal to:
$$ \int_{ 0<y<4,x_3+y>4} f(x_3)g(y)d(y,x_3)=
\frac{1}{6}\int_{0}^{4} e^{-x}x^3 ( \int_{4-x}^{\infty} e^{-y}y\,dy)$$ which is equal to $\frac{96}{5e^4}$. Could somebody check my work, please?